# Want to show a data table populated with data after a button click

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to write a code in this way, that If I click on a button a data table appears populated with data. before that there should not be the data table in view.

```
<p:commandButton value="Go" styleClass="apply_button" actionListener="#{searchBean.getUserList}">
    <f:attribute name="trigram" value="#{searchBean.trigram}"/>
    <f:attribute name="firstName" value="#{searchBean.firstName}"/>
    <f:attribute name="lastName" value="#{searchBean.lastName}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

here the method getUserList() returns a list of data that should be populated in the data table.and it works.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{searchBean.listUser}" var="user">
    <p:column headerText="Trigram">
        <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.trigram}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

It shows in the Data Table after I click on the button, But the Data Table appears before the button click with empty fields. How can I modify my codes to show make the Data Table appear after my button click?
Codes are within the `<h:form>` Tag.

And the Managed Bean `searchBean` is in `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a simple getter/setter :

```
private boolean visible = false; // getter/setter

public void getUserList(ActionEvent event)
{
    setVisible(true);

    // Your code
}
```

And modify your view like this :

```
<p:commandButton value="Go" styleClass="apply_button" actionListener="#{searchBean.getUserList}" update="table-wrapper">
    <f:attribute name="trigram" value="#{searchBean.trigram}"/>
    <f:attribute name="firstName" value="#{searchBean.firstName}"/>
    <f:attribute name="lastName" value="#{searchBean.lastName}"/>
</p:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="table-wrapper">
    <p:dataTable rendered="#{searchBean.visible}" value="#{searchBean.listUser}" var="user">
        <p:column headerText="Trigram">
            <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.trigram}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note the `update` attribute on button, `h:panelGroup` wrapper and `rendered` attribute on table.